Complexity of Finding Independent Sets in Undirected Graphs
Consider the following two problems on undirected graphs:

A: Given G(V,E), does G have an independent set of size |V|-4 ?
B: Given G(V,E), does have an independent set of size 5?

I think both statements are in P. B is definitely as finding all vertex sets of size 5 and
for each of them checking if there is any adjacent vertices.
Is my reasoning correct?
And, I am not sure about the statement A. But, I think it can be done in  a similar way as B.
Can someone clarify whether my reasoning is correct and help me determine the complexity class of these problems? Any insights would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

The number of size-$k$ subsets of $V$ is exactly $\binom{\lvert V \rvert}{k}$. And for any fixed constant $k$, $\binom{\lvert V \rvert}{k}$ is polynomial in $\lvert V \rvert$, same applies to $k = \lvert V \rvert - \text{a constant}$.
